# Check for validation errors in part of a form in JSF

Tags: jsf, seam, facelets

I'm building a Seam application, which is basically a huge form divided into different parts, or modules. I need a way to figure out when a module is "complete", meaning all validation for the fields in that module passes. I then need to do something in the view, setting a css-class or whatever.

Something like:

```
<a:region id="region1">
    <s:div styleClass="#{invalid ? 'errors' : ''}">
       <h:inputText required="true" id="input1" />
       <h:inputText required="true" id="input2" />
       <h:commandButton value="Save this section" reRender="region1" />
    </s:div>
</a:region>
```

I figured I had two options:

- Using some sort of view-logic (like #{invalid} for a single field)
- Using a method in the bean, where I get all components for the module programmatically, and check them for validation errors.

However, I can't find any way to do any of them. Any ideas if this is even possible?

We're using JSF 1.2 with Seam.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) to check if a validation error has occurred on the particular input component.

```
<s:div styleClass="#{!input1.valid or !input2.valid ? 'errors' : ''}">
   <h:inputText binding="#{input1}" required="true" id="input1" />
   <h:inputText binding="#{input2}" required="true" id="input2" />
   <h:commandButton value="Save this section" reRender="region1" />
</s:div>
```

Comment: Nice, that works! However, I also tried binding the components to properties in the bean, but I get a NullpointerException when doing so. Do you know anything about that? I thought it was as simple as using binding="#{myBean.input1}" and then declaring a UIInput-property in the bean..